# Nested If Statements for Multiple Conditionals

Tags: livecycle

I need something similar to the following script (this would ideally go into a LiveCycle "calculate" event field):

```
if(Subform.TextField1.rawValue !== null && Subform.TextField2.rawValue !== null && Subform.TextField3.rawValue !== null &&

Subform.TextField4.rawValue !== null &&

((TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue == null && (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue == null && (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue == null) ||

(TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue !== null && (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue ==  "Yes" && (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue == null) ||

(TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue !== null && (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue ==  "No" && (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue !== null)) &&

((TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField5.rawValue == null && (TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField6.rawValue == null && (TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField7.rawValue == null) ||

(TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField5.rawValue !== null && (TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField6.rawValue ==  "Yes" && (TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField7.rawValue == null) ||

(TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField5.rawValue !== null && (TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField6.rawValue ==  "No" && (TableSubform.Table.Row2.TextField7.rawValue !== null))

)

{

this.rawValue="Complete";

} else {

this.rawValue="Not complete"
```

Basically, I have a form with four fields on top that need to be completed. Then, I have a three column table (first row being the header) with two rows of fillable text fields with the following rules in order for the form to be deemed complete:

If TextField5 is blank, then TextField6 and Textfield7 do not need to be filled in

If TextField5 is not blank, then TextField6 needs to be filled in with "Yes" or "No"

If TextField6 is "Yes," then TextField7 does not need to be filled in

If Textfield6 is "No," then TextField7 does need to be filled in

Please let me know where my script went wrong! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, from what I see this is not nested IF statement, it's a whole one command of and/or. Of course such code is not preferable, so first try to divide your conditions into something like this:

```
if(Subform.TextField1.rawValue !== null && Subform.TextField2.rawValue !== null)

  {
   if(another condition)
  }
      if(another condition).....etc
```

See, doing nested IF statements means for each command, there is other options to do.

For the conditions, if this language is JAVA then you need to use [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

In order to write your commands in, it means when for example your TextField6 is "no", then using ActionListener you will write the command code that TextField7 need to be filled in.

Comment: If I do the nested IF statements (according to your above example), would it create an "and" effect? Like, if(this) AND if(this) is true, then this.rawValue will be set to "Complete." For example, I want these two if statements to be "or": `code` if(TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue == null && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue == null && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue == null)
}
if(TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue !== null && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue ==  "Yes" && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue == null)

Comment: @hy9fesh You can do nested if for your "AND" statements, but for "OR" you have to do it in one line as you wrote.

Comment: thanks for your response! So I would be doing something like this: `if((TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue == null && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue == null && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue == null) || (TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField5.rawValue !== null && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField6.rawValue == "Yes" && TableSubform.Table.Row1.TextField7.rawValue == null))`

Answer (score 0):

> If TextField5 is blank, then TextField6 and Textfield7 do not need to be
>   filled in. If TextField5 is not blank, then TextField6 needs to be filled in with "Yes" or "No".If TextField6 is "Yes," then TextField7 does not need to be filled in.If Textfield6 is "No," then TextField7 does need to be filled in.

Based on your description I would make a set of statements that look like this.

```
if (TextField5.isNull) this.rawValue = "Complete";
else {
  if (TextField6.rawValue == "Yes") this.rawValue = "Complete";
  else {
    if (!TextField7.isNull) this.rawValue = "Complete";
    else this.rawValue = "Not Complete";
  }
}
```

But really, there's only one condition where you can have an incomplete form (it seems): TextField5 is filled, TextField6 is "No", and TextField7 is empty. So, you can condense that down into one statement and mark anything else complete.

```
if (!TextField5.isNull && TextField6.rawValue == "No" && TextField7.isNull) this.rawValue = "Not Complete";
else this.rawValue = "Complete";
```

Comment: I can also have an incomplete form if TextField5 is filled and TextField6 is not filled. That said, will I be able to do `if ((!TextField5.isNull && TextField6.rawValue == "No" && TextField7.isNull) || (!TextField5.isNull && TextField6.isNull)) this.rawValue = "Not Complete";
else this.rawValue = "Complete";`

Comment: Yes, that would include the part I missed and should give you working code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! So if I had two rows, it would be: `if ((!Row1.TextField5.isNull && Row1.TextField6.rawValue == "No" && Row1.TextField7.isNull) || (!Row1.TextField5.isNull && Row1.TextField6.isNull)) {if ((!Row2.TextField5.isNull && Row2.TextField6.rawValue == "No" && Row2.TextField7.isNull) || (!Row2.TextField5.isNull && Row2.TextField6.isNull)) this.rawValue = "Not Complete"; else this.rawValue = "Complete";`

Comment: Since there's only one line of executable code inside your statement, you can drop the brace `{`. About the rows: We're talking about LiveCycle. Are these rows created dynamically in a table? (They would be called 'Row1[0]' and 'Row1[1]'.) Or are these two rows already created and called 'Row1' and 'Row2'?

Comment: All right, this issue has been resolved. For those are you curious, this is what I did: `if ((!Row1.TextField5.isNull && Row1.TextField6.rawValue == "No" && Row1.TextField7.isNull) || (!Row1.TextField5.isNull && Row1.TextField6.isNull)) {if ((!Row2.TextField5.isNull && Row2.TextField6.rawValue == "No" && Row2.TextField7.isNull) || (!Row2.TextField5.isNull && Row2.TextField6.isNull)) this.rawValue = "Not Complete"; else this.rawValue = "Complete";` in addition to the other fields I wanted in my first post, separated by OR instead of AND. It seems to work for me!